# All or one checkbox is selected to enable submit button angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs. I am trying a simple program which have check boxes and a disabled button. The button should be enabled after one or multiple checkboxes are selected. However, my solution seems to be not working. Any help in this respect will be great.
HTML code:

```
   <html ng-app="Apps" ng-controller = "chk">
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Apps.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1> Fruits </h1>
<hr/>
<div >

<label ng-repeat="lbl in lbls">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="chkd" > {{lbl}}
</label>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" ng-disabled="!chkd"/>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the JS is file:

```
    var Apps = angular.module ('Apps', [])
Apps.controller("chk", function($scope){

$scope.lbls = [
    'Apples', 
    'Bananas', 
    'Apricots', 
    'Peaches'
  ];

});
```

Comment: Where is `chkd` defined?

Comment: Oh,  ng-model (chkd) must be defined in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach which you can insert other fruits, and don't need to change code in your `ng-disabled`:

```js
 var Apps = angular.module ('Apps', [])
Apps.controller("chk", function($scope){
$scope.chkd = {
                Apples: false, 
                Bananas: false,
                Apricots: false,
                Peaches: false
                };

$scope.enableSubmit = function(){
  var atLeastOneSelected = [];
  
  for (var fruit in $scope.chkd) {
      if($scope.chkd[fruit] === true){
        atLeastOneSelected.push(fruit);
      }
  }
  
  return !(atLeastOneSelected.length > 0);
}

});
```

```html
<html ng-app="Apps" ng-controller = "chk">
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Apps.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1> Fruits </h1>
<hr/>
<div >

<label ng-repeat="(lbl, enabled) in chkd">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="chkd[lbl]"> {{lbl}}
</label>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" ng-disabled="enableSubmit()"/>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is great @Jose Rojas. May I ask what if the data (fruits) are not hard coded in the chked object? rather dynamically coming from an api in form of json? Thanks ;)

Comment: @MSA AngularJS has $http service to retrieve data from an API, further information here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http, how does your data look like?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have to have separate conditions for each of the checkboxes for ng-disabled to detect a change. Use this HTML layout instead:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"> 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
        <h1> Fruits </h1>
        <hr/>
        <div ng-app>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="cb01"> Apples
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="cb02"> Bananas
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="cb03"> Apricots
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="cb04"> Peaches
            <br>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" ng-disabled="!(cb01||cb02||cb03||cb04)">
        </div>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47t8fbva/)

**EDIT**
Code should now be working fine. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Every time someone uses `?:` with `true` and `false` as the values, a kitten cries. Just use `ng-disabled="!(cb01||cb02||cb03||cb04)"`. Also, wrapping all of the checkboxes in a single label will cause all of them to be checked when clicking on the words.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I don't use Angular so much, I'm more with Electron so I just looked at the docs. Also, it works fine even when wrapped in a single label. Not sure why it wouldn't :)

Comment: Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/g4duhqo3/ it checks and unchecks the first checkbox only, when clicking on, say, "Peaches". Labels are mean to label a single HTML form element.

Comment: My apologies. I just realized I was wrong. My fiddle code isn't wrapped in a label LOL I was sitting here thinking "wtf my code is working perfect, what happened?"

Comment: Thanks @JLynchDesigns. However, I was hoping for a solution using ng-repeat to add checkboxes.

Comment: @MSA No problem! I'm not very familiar with AngularJS but I figured I'd try.

Comment: @MSA take a look of my approach

Comment: @Jose Rojas. Perfect! May I ask what if the data (fruits) are not hard coded in the chked object? rather dynamically coming from an api in form of json? Thanks ;)